# Run time error with array

Tags: c++

I can't understand why I get the run time error:

> the variable ia is being used without being initialized.

However, as far as I can see, I have initialized it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //array dimensions
    const int row_size = 2;
    const int col_size = 4;

    //array definition
    int ia[row_size][col_size] = {{0, 1, 2, 3},{5, 6, 7, 8}};

    cout << ia[2][4];

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ia[2][4]` is invalid. Counting starts from 0, not 1. You probably meant `ia[1][3]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ array indexes are zero-based. So to access the fourth column of the second row, you need to access `ia[1][3]`.

Comment: Ah such a simple oversight... thanks will give you the green mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
ia[2][4]
```

doesn't exist.

```
ia[0..1][0...3]
```

all exist, however.

Try:

```
cout << ia[1][3];
```

---

Arrays in C++ start with the index `0`. `1` is actually the `2`<sup>nd</sup> element. So:

```
int a[2] = {42, 50};

std::cout << a[0] << a[1];   // prints 4250
std::cout << a[2];           // a[2] doesn't exist!
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start from 0, so your `ia[2][4]` will be out of bounds. Should be `ia[1][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0-based, i.e. the first element in an array `a` is `a[0]`. So the last element in an array of 4 elements would be `a[3]`. In your case `ia[1][3]` would give you the sought element I believe.